# Calculate end time based on a timestamp and an interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL. I've been stuck on this problem. I have been able to complete some of it but can't seem to properly input the information to get the end time.

Question: Use an anonymous PL/SQL program to print out the email of the organizer of the event 'Party City' as well as start_time and end time of the event. Use implicit cursor and handle exception.

Here is my progress so far:

```
declare
o_email varchar(70);
s_tart_time timestamp;
begin
select oemail, start_time
into o_email, s_tart_time 
from  organizer o, event e
where e.oid = o.oid and
ename = 'Party City';
dbms_output.put_line ('email is: ' || o_email);
dbms_output.put_line ('start time is: ' || s_tart_time);
Exception
    when no_data_found then
    Dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found');
END;
```

TABLE:

```
create table event
(eid int, --- event id 
oid int, --- organizer id 
ename varchar(50), --- event name 
lid int, --- location id 
start_time timestamp, -- start time of event
duration interval day to second, --- duration of event, 
status int, --- 1 scheduled, 2 canceled, 3 finished 
primary key(eid), 
foreign key (lid) references location,
foreign key (oid) references organizer);

insert into event values (1, 1,'Party City', 1, timestamp '2018-9-6 10:00:00.00',interval '2' hour, 3);
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Very good for a PL/SQL beginner! You chose the proper data types (TIMESTAMP and INTERVAL, instead of VARCHAR and/or NUMBER). Minor issue: Your select may return more than just one row if you have several events named 'Party City'. In this case you would get a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception which you should handle as well.

Comment: Thank you! I was using start_time + duration in the output line instead of in the select line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL supports date/time arithmetic, so you can simply add an interval to a timestamp to get the end time. e.g.:

```
declare
o_email varchar(70);
s_tart_time timestamp;
end_time timestamp;
begin
select oemail, start_time, start_time + duration
into o_email, s_tart_time, end_time
from  organizer o, event e
where e.oid = o.oid and
ename = 'Party City';
dbms_output.put_line ('email is: ' || o_email);
dbms_output.put_line ('start time is: ' || s_tart_time);
dbms_output.put_line ('end time is: ' || end_time);
Exception
    when no_data_found then
    Dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found');
END;
/

email is: bla
start time is: 06-SEP-18 10.00.00.000000 AM
end time is: 06-SEP-18 12.00.00.000000 PM
```

[LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hh2pqs9zw3naf8ai9w62qlrb2) - note: I had to comment out some bits because you didn't include the `organizer` table definition in your question.